# A good way of sharing a settings class across ViewModels in a MVVM scenario

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a MVVM application where some of my VM's rely on some settings from another VM.
E.g. when the user selects a folder in the UI, the change should be passed to another part of the program that uses this folder.
I already have an event aggregator, so I could just subscribe to event messages that could be fired from the VM that handles the folder-picking.

However, if I would like to save the settings to a file, I think it would be better having the settings in a single entity.

The problem is now, what is the better way of implementing such a master-settings entity.
Should it subscribe to a certain `SettingChangedEventMessage` and the update its own internal settings state and publish a `SettingsChangedEventMessage` (note the extra 's'), which all classes that depend on settings should subscribe to, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Events with a mediator will work if the view models are all alive to receive them when they are sent. If the view model life-cycles do not overlap then you will need an intermediary store to place them in. A simple repository pattern would work here, and then you could simply use a DI container to manage the life-span of this repository as a singleton. Your view models would then ask for the reference in their constructors.

Comment: Your proposal sounds good to me - you essentially want your settings consumers to know about settings updates and you want your settings container to know about setting updates. Sounds fine to me. You could also work the other way round where you inject the settings repository into each VM that needs it as a singleton. This way you only have one settings class, there is less plumbing code and you don't need to worry about synchronising the context (you just work directly on the settings object)